# Printing all the hidden properties of an object

Tags: javascript

So I have the empty object `a = {}`. When I do `console.log(a)`, `console.dir(a)`, or even

```
for(b in a) {
   console.log(b);
}
```

I do not get to see the "hidden properties" such as `__defineGetter__`, `hasOwnProperty`, etc.

How can I print *all* properties of an object?

Comment: What browser did you use? In Google Chrome i see all properties of object

Comment: @antyrat I'm using Google Chrome 17 and the only property I see using `console.log` is `__proto__`.

Comment: You can open this property and inside it you will see all non-enumerable properties

Comment: @antyrat: Hum, interesting. Why are they in `__proto__`?

Comment: @Randomblue: If you click the little arrow to the left of `__proto__`, it will show you `__proto__`'s properties (properties the object inherits from its prototype). `{}` has no properties at all, just a prototype.

Comment: You can read more about constructors at MDN site https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're after is the [*non-enumerable*](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.1) properties of an object (and possibly those it inherits from its prototype). I don't believe there's any standard way to get them via JavaScript.

If you use a debugger and inspect an object, usually all properties of an object are shown (not just the enumerable ones). All major browsers have built-in debuggers now: Chrome has Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I); IE8 and up have "F12 Developer Tools"; IE7 and earlier can be debugged via the free version of VS.Net; recent versions of Firefox have tools built in, for older versions you can get the Firebug plug-in; Opera has Dragonfly.

**Update**: In the comments on the question you've said:

> I'm using Google Chrome 17 and the only property I see using `console.log` is `__proto__`.

Right. `{}` has no properties at all, just a prototype. If you click the little arrow to the left of `__proto__`, it will show you `__proto__`'s properties. `hasOwnProperty`, `toString`, etc., are all properties `{}` gets from the prototype (which is `Object.prototype`), not properties of the object itself.

JavaScript uses *prototypical* inheritance, which means an object is backed by a prototype. If you try to retrieve the value of a property the object doesn't have, the JavaScript engine will look at the object's prototype to see if the prototype has that property; if so, that value is used. If the prototype doesn't have it, the engine looks at the *prototype's* prototype; and so on until it reaches the root of the hierarchy. This is why you hear about objects having their **own** properties vs. properties they inherit.

Here's an example:

Here's a constructor function. We put a property on the prototype the JavaScript engine will assign if we use `new Foo` to create an object.

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = 42;
```

Let's create an object using that constructor:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

`f` has no properties at all, and yet:

```
console.log(f.bar); // 42
```

...because since `f` doesn't have a property called "bar", the engine looks on `f`'s prototype, which is the `Foo.prototype` object.

Now let's give `f` its own "bar" property:

```
f.bar = 67;
console.log(f.bar); // 67
```

Now let's **remove** `f`'s "bar" property:

```
delete f.bar;
```

What will happen if we try to retrieve `f.bar` now?

```
console.log(f.bar);
```

If you said `42`, you get top marks. Because `f` no longer has a property called "bar", we go back to getting it from the prototype.

Note that this relationship is **live**, so:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = 96;
console.log(f.bar); // 96
```

In the 3rd edition of ECMAScript (most browsers implement something along the lines of the 3rd edition), the only way to assign a prototype to an object is via a constructor function's `prototype` property, as above. With the 5th edition, a more direct way was added: [`Object.create`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.5), which you can pass a prototype object to directly:

```
var proto = {bar: 42};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
console.log(obj.bar); // 42
proto.bar = 67;
console.log(obj.bar); // 67
```

Answer (score 6):

**`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`**

This will also show every non-enumerable property, although it will not follow the [prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877420/895245) lookup as `.` does.

I don't know any method that both goes up the prototype chain and shows non-enumerables.

Example:

```
var o = Object.create({base:0})
Object.defineProperty(o, 'yes', {enumerable: true})
Object.defineProperty(o, 'not', {enumerable: false})

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o))
// [ 'yes', 'not' ]

console.log(Object.keys(o))
// [ 'not' ]

for (var x in o)
    console.log(x)
// yes, base
```

So we conclude:

- `Object.keys()` does not go up the chain, and does not show non-enumerables
- `for in` goes up the chain but does not show non-enumerables

You could of course manually climb the prototype chain and use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

For the case of `Object`, `__defineGetter__` and `hasOwnProperty` are properties of `Object.prototype` found on `new Object` objects through prototype chain lookup. So you could get them with:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype))
```

Output:

```
[ 'constructor',
  'toString',
  'toLocaleString',
  'valueOf',
  'hasOwnProperty',
  'isPrototypeOf',
  'propertyIsEnumerable',
  '__defineGetter__',
  '__lookupGetter__',
  '__defineSetter__',
  '__lookupSetter__' ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.